# c# Lottery looping program with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, loops, random, boolean

I am currently trying to figure out how to create a program within Visual Studio, that matches 3 numbers, 1-9, given in a textbox with 3 random generated numbers in a listbox. I am having trouble figuring out how to write a WHILE looping statement that'll allow for my listbox to randomly generate 3 numbers at a time and continue if there is no match, but breaks if there is a match, with a max of 1000 attempts. I am a bit lost on how to do this. Thank you for your help.

```
        private void LuckyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random RandomNumber = new Random();
        string newLine = Environment.NewLine;
        int Winning1 = 0;
        int Winning2 = 0;
        int Winning3 = 0;
        int numbers = RandomNumber.Next(10);

        int.TryParse(WinningNumber1.Text, out Winning1);
        int.TryParse(WinningNumber2.Text, out Winning2);
        int.TryParse(WinningNumber3.Text, out Winning3);


        if (Winning1 <= 0 || Winning2 <= 0 || Winning3 <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a number!");
            return;
        }

        while (numbers <= 1000)
        {
            numbers = RandomNumber.Next(10);
        }

    }
```

Comment: It should break once **any** of the three match? Or all three of them?

Comment: Also, it may be worthwhile to clarify whether this is homework or not. There seems to be a strong correlation between 'this is homework' and then later 'I will delete this question, making any effort to assist a waste of time'.

Comment: @mjwills once all three of them match

Comment: I'd suggest storing `Winning1` etc in a `HashSet<int>`. Use `Contains` on it (inside your `while` loop) to see if the entry is there. If it is there, then remove it. When the `Count` of the `HashSet` is 0 then you've matched all three. Also consider what happens if the user of your software writes **the same number** into multiple text boxes.

Comment: @mjwills This is homework, although, I don't plan to delete this question. I just need help. If I shouldn't be asking questions on here related to assignments, I wasn't aware and I apologize.

Comment: To actually make it random, you should change the location of where you create `Random` because it is not as random as one would hope.

Comment: If you are actually writing something someone is going to wager on (like a lottery), don't use System.Random.  It's not a particularly good random number generator for something like that.

Comment: System.Random is perfectly capable of picking numbers from 1-1000.  However, there ought be just one Random object for the app, not a new one for each click, and that while loop is throwing them all away.

Comment: I am supposed to use "Random Variable = new Random();". It's for a project, yet I can't even figure out how to have my list box generate random numbers, let alone match with the numbers given in the textboxes

Comment: @Disaffected1070452 how should I change my while loop to generate numbers from 1-1000? Well technically 1-999.

Comment: You need to think things thru a little more - away from the keyboard.  If the user picked 3 numbers already why do you need to pick 1000?  Also you are not constraining dupes - usually it is X number of different numbers picked.  The easiest thing is to create a pool of 1-1000, shuffle them and take three

Comment: @Disaffected1070452 I guess it wouldn't be 1000, it would be 3 numbers ranging from 1-9. So the user enters 3 numbers in a textbox 1-9, then upon clicking the button, the list box should create matching numbers using the same criteria, 1-9. 123, 456, 987, for example. The loop should continue 1000 times or until a match is reached.

Comment: Yea, I dont know how your game works.  So, in this game you get 1000 chances to match?  Weird, but a) yes your random pick should be 1-9 or 0-9 depending. b) there is nothing about a listbox in that code.  Pick a random number.  Qualify it (like has it been picked yet), if not, add to the listbox (no idea why)...probably need some other control to show those that "hit". Do that until all three are "found" or you hit 1000 reps.  Apparently, they need to match in order???

Comment: @Disaffected1070452 essentially yes, that's how it works. It's a lottery basically. I understand what it's supposed to do, and I can write pseudo code that makes sense to me. I just cant figure out the actual code that is required to make it happen. The 3 random numbers need to match the users entry in order. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: `once all three of them match` I am struggling to reconcile that with the accepted answer.

Comment: @mjwills I've still yet to use the example in visual studio. I'll test it out. It helps with understanding the syntax though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this help you:

```
 private void LuckyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random RandomNumberGenerator = new Random();
        string newLine = Environment.NewLine;
        int Winning1 = 0;
        int Winning2 = 0;
        int Winning3 = 0;
        int randomNumber = RandomNumberGenerator.Next(10);
        int counter = 0;
        int winnerId = 0;


        int.TryParse(WinningNumber1.Text, out Winning1);
        int.TryParse(WinningNumber2.Text, out Winning2);
        int.TryParse(WinningNumber3.Text, out Winning3);


        if (Winning1 <= 0 || Winning2 <= 0 || Winning3 <= 0 ||
            Winning1 > 10 || Winning2 > 10 || Winning3 > 10)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Number!");
            return;
        }

        while (counter < 1000)
        {
            if (Winning1 == randomNumber)
            {
                winnerId = 1;
                break;
            }
            else if (Winning2 == randomNumber)
            {
                winnerId = 2;
                break;
            }
            else if (Winning3 == randomNumber)
            {
                winnerId = 3;
                break;
            }
            randomNumber = RandomNumberGenerator.Next(10);
            counter++;
        }

        if(winnerId != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Number " + winnerId + " wins!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("no one wins!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer probably needs some explanation to it.  Dropping a slab of code with no commentary is just as bad as a question without any code.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! That actually helps a lot!